# a mistake in my application

Tags: visas, uk, applications

I completed the online application form for a UK visa. After I hit submit, I realized that the amount of money I wrote on my application is incorrect. Is there anything I can do to make a correction?

Comment: Yes. Mention this when you go to submit your documents and they may be able to make a small pen and ink correction for you.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. I mentioned it in the Visa Application Center, they let me make the correction in the form with a pen and sign next to it. Then this paper form was submitted along with the other documents. That was it and my visa didn't take any longer to process because of it.